# roblox: DataStore does not loading data

Tags: lua, roblox

I made data store but its not loading saves values.
I tried on actual servers, still nothing.
also its outputs only log, no errors, no warnings.

```
    local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
    local DataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("SkinStats")
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
        local Leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", Player)
        Leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
        local Cash= Instance.new("IntValue", Leaderstats)
        Cash.Name = "Cash" 
        Cash.Value = 100    
        local Kills= Instance.new("IntValue", Leaderstats)
        Kills.Name = "Kills" 
        Kills.Value = 0
    
        local Data = DataStore:GetAsync(Player.UserId)
        print(Data)
        if Data then
            Cash.Value = Data["Cash"]
            Kills.Value = Data["Kills"]
            print("also works")
        end
    end)
    
    game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player)
        DataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, {
            ["Cash"] = Player.leaderstats.Cash.Value; 
            ["Kills"] = Player.leaderstats.Kills.Value; 
        })
    end)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the way you're saving the data. You need to add comma `","` not semi-colon `";"`.

```lua
 
    game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player)
        DataStore:SetAsync(Player.UserId, {
            ["Cash"] = Player.leaderstats.Cash.Value,
            ["Kills"] = Player.leaderstats.Kills.Value
        })
    end)
```